# EA API for Toolset menu option

Tags: c#, enterprise-architect

I am working on Form creation in Enterprise Architect using C# Add-In. I wanted to know if there is any EA API available for displaying Toolset menu option while adding new element as shown below:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Adding how? Be more specific.

Comment: I want to add elements in a package  in EA through my C# Add-In depending on Toolset option(eg : UseCase option from UseCase Toolset menu) selected by user. It would be of great help if any API is available for displaying the Toolset menu option to the user.

Comment: That does not make your question any clearer.

Comment: Sorry, In EA on right click of particular package a menu opens , in which we can select Add element option. on selection of add element option a window opens which consists of options such as Name,Type,Toolset as shown above. On click of Toolset option the list of Toolsets are displayed.I want to implement the same in my Add-In.

Comment: I see. EA has EA_OnContextMenuItemChanged (or the like). But I have not Windoze experience so I don't know how to open a menu. EA does not provide that.

Comment: Please edit your question so the comment will be seen there.

Answer (score 1):

No by default EA doesn't provide any API call for it .

You need to set the stereotype manually in the element class.

Comment: _[Not so sure about that](http://sparxsystems.com/resources/developers/autint.html)_